# Georgian texts (latin)

Tags: georgian-language

I wish to translate Georgian texts (written in Latin alphabet, not in their specific symbols) to English. Google translate did not help me at all (I am wondering why). Is there any other tool which can help me with this?

The reason why I am doing this may seem quite stupid - I want to read comments under my photo in Facebook. But it is important for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translation.

Comment: I agree that for the stated purpose ("read Facebook comments") the question is off-topic. However, the question and its answer can help with legitimate travel concerns (e.g. travelers to Georgia in this case). When I was traveling in countries with non-Latin scripts (e.g. China, Mongolia), little tips and tricks to help input such text and then translate it were definitely "on-topic" and critical for a good travel experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility: Go to http://ge.translit.net/ , type in the Latin characters (I don't think you can copy&paste) and it will convert them to Georgian characters as you type. Then copy these characters and paste them into Google Translate.

Seems to have worked for me - e.g. type "genacvali" into ge.translit.net - get "გენაცვალი" - paste this into Google Translate, get "dear" as translation.

Comment: For some reason I thought that this tool can only be used on Russian language... Thanks :)